# creating and calling a function with more than 100 parameters

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a function with 135 parameters.
I am getting the error.

> cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function

Creation of the function with 135 parameters

```
create or replace  function Alloc_func(
P_paramter1 numeric,
P_paramter2 varchar,
P_paramter3 numeric,
.
.
.
P_paramter135 numeric)
RETURNS void AS
$$
declare
  begin
  raise notice 'My 135 parameters function';
  end $$ language plpgsql;
```

calling the function with 135 parameters

```
create or replace  function call_func1() RETURNS void AS
    $$
  begin
 perform                    Alloc_func(
                            P_paramter1   => null,
                            P_paramter1   => 'JACK',
                            P_paramter1   => 1,
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            P_paramter135 => 100)
raise notice '135 parametesrs function called';                             
  end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Created type with 135 parameters and passed as parameter to  the function  Alloc_func.

```
 do $$
    begin
    create type type_parmaters as(
                                        P_paramter1    NUMERIC,
                                        P_paramter2    VARCHAR,
                                        P_paramter3    NUMERIC,
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        P_paramter135    NUMERIC);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
    END $$; 

create or replace  function Alloc_func(p_type_parmaters type_parmaters)
P_paramter1 numeric,
P_paramter2 varchar,
P_paramter3 numeric,
.
.
.
P_paramter135 numeric)
RETURNS void AS
$$
declare
  begin
  raise notice 'My 135 parameters function';
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Could you please help me how to call the function Alloc_func with parameter values.

Comment: You can create an [object type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) with 135 fields, then pass an instance of that type. But that many parameters for a function is typically code smell and more often than not this indicates a poor design

Comment: WTH are that many parameters for?

Comment: Hi,
Created type with 135 parameters and passesd as parameter to  the function  Alloc_func.
Could you please help me how to call the function Alloc_func with parameter values.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, Could anybody please help me.

Comment: Hi All, Please help me.